# What is LLFC_PAUSE_FRAME in nexus?

Tags: nx-os

Sometimes in my N3K i receive the following error :

```
2020 Oct 22 13:35:37 HOSTNAME %-SLOT1-2-BCM_SYSLOG_LLFC_PAUSE_FRAME: 972 LLFC pause frames received on Ethernet1/1
2020 Oct 22 13:35:39 HOSTNAME  %-SLOT1-2-BCM_SYSLOG_LLFC_PAUSE_FRAME: 430 LLFC pause frames received on Ethernet1/2
```

what are these errors? can i ignore them?
they are not so much every week or such period of time i will see these errors,
THanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are no errors, just information.

The switch reports link-level flow control pause frames (802.3x pause frames) that have been received on those ports.

Pause frames are generated and received when the destination (or a switch in between) begins to be overwhelmed by traffic (e.g. queue buffer or CPU capacity exceeded). Depending on your network setup and potential bottlenecks you might want to investigate the underlying issue or simply ignore those messages.

By default, pause frames are often enabled on end devices, but disabled on network switches. When the switches don't propagate them they're effectively disabled.

Pause frames can cause performance problems in not carefully designed networks because they cause head-of-line blocking. One of the applications that regularly profits from pause frames is iSCSI.

Comment: Are pause frames enabled? I've never seen my collection of nexuses emit that message. (and yes, pause frames are happening)